How to map nested arrays in thymeleaf
This is my code:
My classes:
public class Persons {

    List<Student> students;
}

public class Student {

    List<String> role;
}

In thymeleaf:
<select id="role" tabindex="16" class="form-select input-widget custom-size" th:field="*{students[0].role[0]}">
    <option value="1">Mathematician</option>
    <option value="2">Economist</option>                                                                          
</select>

It means that every student can have multiple roles. The issue is that the program iterate only the first array (i.e. students[1].role[0], students[2].role[0]), but not the second array. Is there a way to control which array will iterated? I want that in this select tag only the second array is iterated.
I tried the above example, but only the first array is iterated.

It should look something like this:
<th:block th:each="student, i: *{students}">
  <th:block th:each="role, j: ${student.role}">
    <select tabindex="16" class="form-select input-widget custom-size" th:field="*{students[__${i.index}__].role[__${j.index}__]}">
      <option value="1">Mathematician</option>
      <option value="2">Economist</option>                                                                          
    </select>
  </th:block>
</th:block>


This solution assumes that the items in the arrays are already filled. My issue aims to add the current item to the inner array and not to read from it.
